# How to allow only admin user can access Firebase realtime database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm new to firebase,
I am trying to have a Firebase realtime database where only the admin can write the data, the user only can read the data.

I have seen the documentation that uses log-in(authentication) logic to control it.

I'm not really sure I can implement like the below code, only admin uid can write the data, if that work how do I find the admin uid(xxxxxxxx)?. Thanks.

```
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth.uid === 'xxxxxxxx'"
  }
}
```

Comment: I need something like this but for Firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's totally valid if you want to allow that 1 user only to write data. [`auth.uid`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#authentication) is UID of user attempting to write data and that checks if it matches your Admin ID.

If there can be multiple admins, [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) are useful too.

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck on how to find the admin UID.

Comment: @leojail when you create a user in Firebase Authentication, you can get the UID from the [Firebase Auth Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/users)

Answer (score 0):

Firestore security rules accept:

```css
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == 'specific_admin_uid';
    }
  }
}
```